# Metro Ui Security Architecture

Tags: security, architecture, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Does anyone know of any article/publication on the security architecture of Metro app?

1. For example, can the metro app call an external service. If it can,
   under what condition. Will it prompt the user first? And if so will
   they be able to change their restriction later and how?
2. Cross domain scripting in a website is usually considered a big
   no-no. But if I were to turn the same code into a metro app (since
   presumably they're both written in Html 5 + js), does it mean I can
   make ajax calls to any server irrespective of their domain? Is it
   even possible to port a website into an app? If so how easy is that?
3. What about accessing local file system? Or does it have to go
   through the contracts to do so?
4. And this is kind of related but if I were to write a website (not an
   app). And the site was opened using Metro IE10, can it subscribe
   into the metro specific js events? I guess I'm trying to figure out
   how to save cost by doing as little development as possible. I
   prefer a website that can target multiple platforms and only target
   specific platform for the features that absolutely require it - also
   not to thrilled with the idea of having to go through microsoft in
   order to publish my app.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metro applications can call into web services located on other machines, but their ability to interact with the local machine is severely limited.

Similarly, accessing arbitrary parts of the local filesystem is not permitted.  If your application has the documents (or music or photos) library permission, it can access the files in those libraries.

Comment: Ok so how about a regular website opened in ie10, does it have access to the underlying api if so how much of that is accessible? Where can I find these docs?

Comment: I answered the parts of the question that I could answer authoritatively.  The windows runtime APIs are *not* available to web sites when using IE10, except in the context of W3C defined APIs.  Some events (like MSPointerUp/MSPointerDown/MSPointerMove) are available in IE 10 - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/20/touch-input-for-ie10-and-metro-style-apps.aspx for info on the pointer APIs